# Highlight a specific point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this:

```
item <- c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item1", "item2", "item3")
group <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C")
level <- c(NA, NA, 40, NA, 25, NA, 30, NA, NA)

data <- cbind(item, group, level)
data <- as_tibble(data)
data <- type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)
```

Which appears as follows:

```
item  group level

item1    A    NA
item2    B    NA
item3    C    40
item1    A    NA
item2    B    25
item3    C    NA
item1    A    30
item2    B    NA
item3    C    NA
```

Every item is univocally associated to a specific group ( `item1`  is always linked to `group A`,  `item2` always to  `group B` , etc.)

To plot the graph of the data, I use this code:

```
   graph <- data %>%
     ggplot(aes(x=group, y=level)) +
     geom_point(colour="blue", size=3, na.rm=TRUE)
```

which shows this result:

[image]

Now, I would like to display in red the point with value  `25` , selecting it by the item.
I.e., "if the  `item2`  (which corresponds to  `group B` ) has a value != NA, display its value in red, keeping all the other values in blue".

I have thought to a  `if`  in a  `for-cycle` , but I don't know if it is the right reasoning.

Thank you for helping!

**CLOSED:** SOLUTION FOUND

I have created a subset of the dataframe by item:

```
my_dot <- subset(data, item=="item2")
my_dot <- type.convert(my_dot, as.is = TRUE)
```

and added a line to the ggplot which load the subsetted dataframe "my_plot" in `geom_point(data=my_dot, ...)`

```
    graph <- data %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=group, y=level)) +
      geom_point(colour="blue", size=3, na.rm=TRUE) +
      geom_point(data=my_dot, aes(x=group, y=level), colour="red", size=5, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Here the result I was looking for:

[image]

Comment: I agree with @stefan's link. Regardless, I see no reason for a `for` loop or `if`-conditional to do this: the single plot with different point highlights should be done in a single step.

Comment: I closed it as a dupe, since the other answer (which has much more traffic, more answers, more variety) really addresses it fully. I provided an answer anyway just to personalize it for you, you can still accept it if you like, but there is no requirement. If I missed something and the duplicate (and my answer) is insufficient, ping me and we can discuss and reopen.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dupe, but for your data, a few options:

1. `aes(color=(group == "B"))`, so we should always have two colors.

   ```r
   ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=level)) +
     geom_point(aes(color=(group == "B")), size=3, na.rm=TRUE) +
     scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
   ```

   [image]
2. `aes(color=group)`, where we can specify different colors for each group. We'll name the color-vector:

   ```r
   ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=level)) +
     geom_point(aes(color=group), size=3, na.rm=TRUE) + 
     scale_color_manual(values=c(A="blue", B="red", C="blue"))
   ```

   [image]
3. Overlay a new point over the old:

   ```r
   ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=level)) +
     geom_point(color="blue", size=3, na.rm=TRUE) +
     geom_point(color="red", size=3, na.rm=TRUE, data = ~subset(., group == "B"))
   ```

   [image]

   (This is generally not the "canonical" method of `ggplot2`; note that it does not add a legend, because we've not assigned a field to the color aesthetic.)

   (The `data=` here uses `~ subset(.)`. The tilde `~` and dot `.` are important. You can use `dplyr::filter(., ...)` if you prefer.)

(For those with legends, the legend can be removed with `guide=NULL` or renamed with `name=".."`, added to the `scale_color_manual` call.)

Comment: Many thanks for your help r2evans. Yes, your advice is a "little" dupe and actually my dataframe is more complex... I have only simplified it to explain my issue. I think the linked answer doesn't really fix my problem... Moreover, I didn't want to select the "red point" using the label "group", but using the "item" linked to the group. Despite this, I have found useful your last suggestion (3.)! At the end, I have used the function ```subsect()``` to select a section of my dataframe by "item" and then I came to the solution I was looking for!

Comment: You can still use the first two, changing `color=(group=="B")` to `color=(item=="item2")` for the same effect, there is no restriction on using a variable that is already assign to an axis/aesthetic. Glad it worked, regardless.